# Automate removing the last page of a bunch of PDFs

Tags: pdf, automation

I have a folder containing hundreds of PDFs, and I would like to remove the last page of each one in a quick way. How can I let my Mac automate this task? Do I need additional software to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this using the [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](http://community.coherentpdf.com).

You can download either the pre-built tools or the *source code* to compile the later on your own, however the latter requires OCaml be installed when compiling. So the pre-built tools are the easiest way to go. The downloaded distribution file, e.g. *cpdf-binaries-master.zip*, contains binaries for Linux, OS X/macOS and Windows and is ~5 MB in size.

Once downloaded and extracted *(double-clicking the .zip file)* you'd copy the, e.g. *~/Downloads/cpdf-binaries-master/OSX-Intel/cpdf*, file to a location that is defined in the `PATH` *environment variable*, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/` to make it *globally* available on the command line in Terminal. If it's not in the `PATH` then you'll have to use the *fully qualified pathname* to the `cpdf` executable or `./cpdf` if it's in the present working directory (`pwd`). In Terminal, type `echo $PATH`so show the `PATH`.

The *syntax* for removing the last page when the PDF file has 3 or more pages is:

```
cpdf in.pdf 1-~2 -o out.pdf
```

The *syntax* for removing the last page when the PDF file has 2 pages is:

```
cpdf in.pdf 1 -o out.pdf
```

Because `cpdf` reads the original file (*in.pdf*) and writes to a new file (*out.pdf*) the *out.pdf* filename needs to be different if saved to the same location as the *in.pdf* file, or save it to a different location with the same *in.pdf* filename as the *out.pdf* filename, or whatever *out.pdf* filename you want.

Below, I'll show two examples of automation using `cpdf` to remove the last page of a PDF file, assuming it has two or more pages. One using an **Automator** *workflow* as a *Service* available in **Finder** on the *Services Context Menu* and the other as a `bash` *script*, to use in Terminal.

**As an Automator Service Workflow available in Finder on the Services Context Menu:**

---

In Automator create a new *service workflow* using the settings as shown in the image below and copy and paste the *code* below the image into the **Run Shell Script** *action* and save as e.g.: **Remove Last Page from PDF**

To use **Remove Last Page from PDF**, in **Finder** select the PDF files you want to remove the last page from and then select **Remove Last Page from PDF** from the **Context Menu** via *right-click* or *control-click*, or from **Finder** > **Services** > **Remove Last Page from PDF**

[image: Automator Service Workflow]

---

```
for f in "$@"; do
        # Get Page Count.
    p="$(/usr/local/bin/cpdf -info "$f" | awk '/Pages:/{print $2}')"
        # Get file extension.
    ext="${f##*.}"
        # Get filename without extension.
    fn="${f%.*}"
        # Rename original file to "filename (original).pdf".
        # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
    mv -n "$f" "${fn} (original).${ext}"
        # If page count is greater than 2, set 'p' to '3' as any
        # PDF with more than 2 pages the command will be the same.
    if [[ $p -gt 2 ]]; then
        p="3"
    fi
    case "$p" in
        3)
                # PDF file has 3 or more pages.
            /usr/local/bin/cpdf "${fn} (original).${ext}" 1-~2 -o "$f" 
            ;;
        2)
                # PDF file has 2 pages.
            /usr/local/bin/cpdf "${fn} (original).${ext}" 1 -o "$f"
            ;;
        1)
                # PDF file has 1 page. Make a copy to the
                # original name for consistency of output.
                # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
            cp -n "${fn} (original).${ext}" "$f"
            ;;      
    esac
        # If you don't want to keep the original
        # file, remove '#' from the next line.
    # rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"
done
```

---

Note that the `PATH` passed a **Run Shell Script** *action* in **Automator** is, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So the *code* above is using the *fully qualified pathname* to the `cpdf` *executable*, `/usr/local/bin/cpdf` as that is where I placed it so as to be available in **Terminal** by way of using its name `cpdf`, only.

Also note that if you do not want to keep the original files, then uncomment (remove the `#` from in front of) the `# rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"` *command*, just above the last line of *code* `done`.

---

**As a `bash` *script* to use in Terminal:**

---

Create the `bash` *script* in the following manner:

In Terminal:

```
touch rlpfpdf
open rlpfpdf
```

Copy the *code block*, starting with `#!/bin/bash`, below into the opened `rlpfpdf` document and then save it.

Back in Terminal:

Make the *script* executable:

```
chmod u+x rlpfpdf
```

Now move the `rlpfpdf` *script* to, e.g.: `/usr/local/bin/`

```
sudo mv rlpfpdf /usr/local/bin/
```

You can then change directory `cd ...` to a directory that has the PDF files that you want to remove the last page from and then simply type `rlpfpdf` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The original files will be moved to "*filename (original).pdf*" and the newly create PDF file sans the last page, if 2 or more pages, will have the original `filename.pdf` name.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf *.PDF; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
            # Get Page Count.
        p="$(cpdf -info "$f" | awk '/Pages:/{print $2}')"
            # Get file extension.
        ext="${f##*.}"
            # Get filename without extension.
        fn="${f%.*}"
            # Rename original file to "filename (original).pdf".
            # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
        mv -n "$f" "${fn} (original).${ext}"
            # If page count is greater than 2, set 'p' to '3' as any
            # PDF with more than 2 pages the command will be the same.
        if [[ $p -gt 2 ]]; then
            p="3"
        fi
        case "$p" in
            3)
                    # PDF file has 3 or more pages.
                cpdf "${fn} (original).${ext}" 1-~2 -o "$f" 
                ;;
            2)
                    # PDF file has 2 pages.
                cpdf "${fn} (original).${ext}" 1 -o "$f"
                ;;
            1)
                    # PDF file has 1 page. Make a copy to the
                    # original name for consistency of output.
                    # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
                cp -n "${fn} (original).${ext}" "$f"
                ;;      
        esac
            # If you don't want to keep the original
            #  file, remove '#' from the next line.
        # rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"
    fi
done
```

---

Note that the *code* above assumes the `cpdf` *executable* is in a *directory* that is within the `PATH` *environment variable*, e.g.: `/usr/local/bin/`

Also note that if you do not want to keep the original files, then uncomment (remove the `#` from in front of) the `# rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"` *command*, just above the last line of *code* `done`.

Comment: I just have 1 simple inquiry. How can I modify the code block to remove the first page instead of the last?

Comment: @InterestedLearner, Within the downloaded distribution file, e.g. _cpdf-binaries-master.zip_, there is the _cpdfmanual.pdf_ file and under "1.2 Input Ranges", starting on page 2, it discusses this. The syntax to remove the first page is `cpdf in.pdf 2-end out.pdf` The _code_ provided in my answer to your OP is specific to removing the last page and you can't just simply use `2-end` in place of `1-~2` or `1` within the _script_ as it's written. You'd have to recode it to match the conditions. If you post a new question I'll post a _script_ that's conducive to the conditions.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274291/automate-removing-the-first-page-of-a-bunch-of-pdfs

Comment: Hey, @user3439894, very nice response. The syntax `cpdf in.pdf 1-~2 -o out.pdf` now works for 2-page documents as well. It'd be great if you could edit your answer accordingly. This will simplify the script a lot.