# Automate removing the first page of a bunch of PDFs

Tags: automator, pdf

I have the `cpff`, and I would like to let my Mac automate removing the first page of many PDF's. I already have a script to remove the last page from my previous question, [Automate removing the last page of a bunch of PDFs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273853/automate-removing-the-last-page-of-a-bunch-of-pdfs).

How can I change the code in the answer to that question to remove the first page instead of the last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this using the [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](http://community.coherentpdf.com).

You can download either the pre-built tools or the *source code* to compile the later on your own, however the latter requires OCaml be installed when compiling. So the pre-built tools are the easiest way to go. The downloaded distribution file, e.g. *cpdf-binaries-master.zip*, contains binaries for Linux, OS X/macOS and Windows and is ~5 MB in size.

Once downloaded and extracted *(double-clicking the .zip file)* you'd copy the, e.g. *~/Downloads/cpdf-binaries-master/OSX-Intel/cpdf*, file to a location that is defined in the `PATH` *environment variable*, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/` to make it *globally* available on the command line in Terminal. If it's not in the `PATH` then you'll have to use the *fully qualified pathname* to the `cpdf` executable or `./cpdf` if it's in the present working directory (`pwd`). In Terminal, type `echo $PATH`so show the `PATH`.

The *syntax* for removing the first page when the PDF file has 2 or more  pages is:

```
cpdf in.pdf 2-end -o out.pdf
```

Because `cpdf` reads the original file (*in.pdf*) and writes to a new file (*out.pdf*) the *out.pdf* filename needs to be different if saved to the same location as the *in.pdf* file, or save it to a different location with the same *in.pdf* filename as the *out.pdf* filename, or whatever *out.pdf* filename you want.

Below, I'll show two examples of automation using `cpdf` to remove the first page of a PDF file, assuming it has two or more pages. One using an **Automator** *workflow* as a *Service* available in **Finder** on the *Services Context Menu* and the other as a `bash` *script*, to use in Terminal.

**As an Automator Service Workflow available in Finder on the Services Context Menu:**

---

In Automator create a new *service workflow* using the settings as shown in the image below and copy and paste the *code* below the image into the **Run Shell Script** *action* and save as e.g.: **Remove First Page from PDF**

To use **Remove First Page from PDF**, in **Finder** select the PDF files you want to remove the first page from and then select **Remove First Page from PDF** from the **Context Menu** via *right-click* or *control-click*, or from **Finder** > **Services** > **Remove First Page from PDF**

[image: Automator Service Workflow Image]

---

```
for f in "$@"; do
            # Get Page Count.
        p="$(/usr/local/bin/cpdf -info "$f" | awk '/Pages:/{print $2}')"
            # Get file extension.
        ext="${f##*.}"
            # Get filename without extension.
        fn="${f%.*}"
            # Rename original file to "filename (original).pdf".
            # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
        mv -n "$f" "${fn} (original).${ext}"
        case "$p" in
            1)
                    # PDF file has 1 page. Make a copy to the
                    # original name for consistency of output.
                    # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
                cp -n "${fn} (original).${ext}" "$f"
                ;;
            *)
                    # PDF file has 2 or more pages.
                    # Remove the first page.
                /usr/local/bin/cpdf "${fn} (original).${ext}" 2-end -o "$f" 
                ;;      
        esac
            # If you don't want to keep the original
            #  file, remove '#' from the next line.
        # rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"
done
```

---

Note that the `PATH` passed a **Run Shell Script** *action* in **Automator** is, `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So the *code* above is using the *fully qualified pathname* to the `cpdf` *executable*, `/usr/local/bin/cpdf` as that is where I placed it so as to be available in **Terminal** by way of using its name `cpdf`, only.

Also note that if you do not want to keep the original files, then uncomment (remove the `#` from in front of) the `# rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"` *command*, just above the last line of *code* `done`.

---

**As a `bash` *script* to use in Terminal:**

---

Create the `bash` *script* in the following manner:

In Terminal:

```
touch rfpfpdf
open rfpfpdf
```

Copy the *code block*, starting with `#!/bin/bash`, below into the opened `rfpfpdf` document and then save it.

Back in Terminal:

Make the *script* executable:

```
chmod u+x rfpfpdf
```

Now move the `rfpfpdf` *script* to, e.g.: `/usr/local/bin/`

```
sudo mv rfpfpdf /usr/local/bin/
```

You can then change directory `cd ...` to a directory that has the PDF files that you want to remove the first page from and then simply type `rfpfpdf` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The original files will be moved to "*filename (original).pdf*" and the newly create PDF file sans the first page, if 2 or more pages, will have the original `filename.pdf` name.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf *.PDF; do
    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
            # Get Page Count.
        p="$(cpdf -info "$f" | awk '/Pages:/{print $2}')"
            # Get file extension.
        ext="${f##*.}"
            # Get filename without extension.
        fn="${f%.*}"
            # Rename original file to "filename (original).pdf".
            # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
        mv -n "$f" "${fn} (original).${ext}"
        case "$p" in
            1)
                    # PDF file has 1 page. Make a copy to the
                    # original name for consistency of output.
                    # Use '-n' to not overwrite an existing file.
                cp -n "${fn} (original).${ext}" "$f"
                ;;
            *)
                    # PDF file has 2 or more pages.
                    # Remove the first page.
                cpdf "${fn} (original).${ext}" 2-end -o "$f" 
                ;;      
        esac
            # If you don't want to keep the original
            #  file, remove '#' from the next line.
        # rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"
    fi
done
```

---

Note that the *code* above assumes the `cpdf` *executable* is in a *directory* that is within the `PATH` *environment variable*, e.g.: `/usr/local/bin/`

Also note that if you do not want to keep the original files, then uncomment (remove the `#` from in front of) the `# rm "${fn} (original).${ext}"` *command*, just above the last line of *code* `done`.

Answer (score 3):

For a solution that will run on MacOS without additional third-party tools, the following python script will remove the front page from a PDF. It will process PDF filenames sent as arguments, or it can be used in an Automator Quick Action.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

from Quartz import PDFDocument
import sys
from Foundation import NSURL

def removePage(filename):
    filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
    pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
    pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
    if pdfDoc:
        pageNum = pdfDoc.pageCount()
        if pageNum > 1:
            pdfDoc.removePageAtIndex_(0)
            pdfDoc.writeToFile_(filename)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        removePage(filename)
```

Comment: @Konrad That's a different Quartz, I think. Quartz is Apple's fundamental Graphics framework. However, what is a shame is that Apple have removed any sort of 'default' python from the OS. You can still install python3 and pyobjc (which includes the Quartz python library), but you can no longer just hand people a python script if they don't know how to install it all first.

Answer (score 1):

I modified @user3439894's script to work with Hazel. This version has the following changes to work with Hazel:

1. Since Hazel processes each file individually, there's no need for a loop.
2. Reference the individual file using `$1` instead of `$f` as per Hazel's instructions
3. Removed code that creates a backup original copy. Otherwise Hazel continues to process the newly created original file when it's saved and it repeats in an infinite loop.

In Hazel, select the `Run Shell Script` option in the action area. Use an embedded script and paste the code below into the text field.

I suggest creating a  designated folder which to apply this rule, otherwise you risk this rule removing the first page of PDFs when you don't want it to. This is especially important now that a backup original is no longer created.

```
# Get Page Count.
p="$(/usr/local/bin/cpdf -info "$1" | awk '/Pages:/{print $2}')"

# Get file extension.
ext="${1##*.}"

# Get filename without extension.
fn="${1%.*}"

# Remove page 1 of PDF if there is more than one page.
case "$p" in
    1)
        # PDF file has 1 page. Do nothing.
        ;;
    *)
        # PDF file has 2 or more pages - Remove the first page.
/usr/local/bin/cpdf "${fn}.${ext}" 2-end -o "$1" 
;;      
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be also easily achieved using ghost script

```sh
for f in "$@"
do
    /usr/local/bin/gs -o "$f-tmp" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=2 "$f"
    mv "$f-tmp" "$f"
done
```

If implemented in Automator as a Quick Action (former service) it would look like that:

[image: Automator implementation]